# how to iterate icons by specific numbers in angular material

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-material

So how can i iterate this?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuOKN.png)

I want to show star icon by numbers. If the rarity in 2 then show 2 stars, if rarity is 5 then show 5 stars etc..

Thanks!

Comment: The link is an image not code. However you should probably use an *ngFor="let i of rarity"

Comment: not the best answer

Comment: @AndreiBucur It's not an answer. You need to include detail so it's easier for us to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code [YourUpdatedCode](https://stackblitz.com/edit/aplicatie-t4rtuk)

```
<div>
  <span><strong>Rarity: </strong></span>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of [].constructor(char.rarity);">
    <span class="material-icons">stars</span>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I think there is no need of index `let i = index` so removed that.

Comment: yes, that is not needed. you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use OnChange event of angular in you `char-detail.component.ts` component.

See the below code

**char-detail.component.ts**

```
export class CharDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() char: Char;
  charArr: any[];
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private messageService: MessageService) {}

  sendMessage(): void {
    this.messageService.sendMessage('Character/Item added!');
  };
  clearMessage(): void {
    this.messageService.clearMessages();
  };
  openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogDataComponent, {
      data: {
        description: 'May the light be with you champion!'
      }
    });
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes);
    if (changes.char.currentValue) {
      this.charArr = new Array(changes.char.currentValue.rarity)
    }
  }
}
```

And in your HTML use this.

```
<span class="material-icons" *ngFor="let i of charArr" >stars</span>
```

Find stackblitz for more details.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/aplicatie-bqwzdd

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is not working either

Comment: can you provide your code? so can i can help you more.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/aplicatie  
this is my app, go to chars>click any char and scope for rarity, i need to automate the star icons by the asssigned rarity number

Comment: please find my edited answer. Also given stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/aplicatie-bqwzdd

Comment: You are great! Thanks

Comment: please approve my answer and upvote. Thanks